# Node.js TCP Out of order and retransmission issues

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, tcp

I am coding a server implementation of a game and I have come across some TCP related issues.

These TCP issues mess up the packet encryption, and so I wanted to ask you guys if may know an answer to my problems.

I tried to fix it myself but i couldn't find anything online for Node.js's net libary.

The issues I am having: TCP Out of order and Retransmissions

How can I re-order packets and how can I ignore retransmissions if I already received the packet.

Comment: TCP is a stream protocol and already takes care of packet re-ordering and retransmissions. You will only get one copy of the data, in the correct order.

Comment: Are you sure you are not using UDP for the game? Can you post a minimal example that demonstrates the problem?

Comment: I just fixed it! route add <server_ip> 255.255.255.255 <gateway_ip> metric 1 -p

Comment: @SomeoneSomething Your solution implies that the problem is that your network connection was messed up. Not that TCP was giving you data out of order (which is impossible)

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you are not using UDP?

Because packet retransmission and ordering is completely transparent with TCP. The protocol handles that all for you and you never get anything out of order, duplicated etc. - unless you mess something up on the application level, in which case TCP will not be able to help you with that but neither would UDP or any other protocol.